# Users Online PHP

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have this login class:

```
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['some_session'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['time_session'] = time();
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }
```

and my user_online script:

```
public function check_if_logged_in() {
    if(time() - $_SESSION['time_session'] > 3600) {
        session_start();
        $users->logout($_SESSION['some_session']);

        session_start();
        session_destroy();

        header("Location: index.php?e=expired");
        exit();
    }
}
```

And also my logout class:

```
public function logout($username) {
    $j = 0;
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE blog_users SET is_online=? WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $j, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

My problem: when a user tries to navigate, my system checks if the user has elapsed 3600 of being online, and if he/she has, it logs them out. What I want to happen: Without a user navigating, if the user has elapsed 3600 of online time, it should automatically update their is_online status to 0 in the database, is it possible? You might be wondering why have I done the is_online table, it is because I want to show the users online.

Comment: Simplest way is to use javascript. start a timer on page load. when the user moves reset the time. when the timer reaches the limit redirect to a page where the user gets logged out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your user logout automatically if he/she do not performance any action you have to check with javascript or using ajax and store in some place every action..

The javascrip solution

something like this should work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  countDown();
  $('body')
          .change(function() {//reset the counter if change any value in 
                              //the page http://api.jquery.com/change/
    resetCounter();
  })
          .mousemove(function() {//reset the counter if the mouse is moved inside the body element
                                 //http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/
    resetCounter()
  })
          .click(function() {//reset the counter if the click inside the body element
                             //http://api.jquery.com/click/
    resetCounter()
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {//reset the counter if make scroll
                              //http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
    resetCounter()
  });
});
var seconds = 3600; //set the var seconds to the time you want start to check
function countDown() {
  if (seconds <= 0) {//when the time over execute
    window.location = "logout.php";
  }
  seconds--;//run every second to decrees a second
  window.setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);

}
function resetCounter() {//reset counter
  seconds = 3600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know javascript/ajax, can you explain what this code does? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @EmilioGort please explain what this code does, I really appreciate your work. Plus should I have the jQuery library linked as well?

Comment: I added comment to my code, and yes you must include the jquery library to this code work

Comment: @Hassan What didnt work?? http://itbelong.com/tongoy/test/index.php look in the source code, note body css, you have to set a body area.